# Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044 will not run on my new iMac

Tags: java, macos, aptana3

I cannot get Aptana Studio 3.6.1 to run on my new iMac. When I start Aptana Studio I get the following Alert:

The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk 1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/ ../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

I click on OK and nothing else ever happens. What do I need to do to get this fixed?

This is a brand new iMac with OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

same thing was happening to me, running 10.10.3... I resolved it by re-installing Java via this link, then rebooting:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

worked like a champ!